# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, php-7

A custom field extension is added to a blog plugin causing this error **"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array"** I'm using PHP7 I tried to use array_key_exists() but this didn't solve the error it accidentally disabled the extension

```
public function getCustomFields()
  {
    $cfData = getXML(BLOGCUSTOMFIELDS);
    $cf = array('options' => '', 'main' => '');
    $count_options = 0;
    $count_main = 0;
    $count_opt = 0;
    foreach($cfData->item as $custom_field)
    {
      if($custom_field->area == 'options')
      {
        $cf['options'][$count_options]['key'] = (string) $custom_field->desc;
        $cf['options'][$count_options]['label'] = (string) $custom_field->label;
        $cf['options'][$count_options]['type'] = (string) $custom_field->type;
        $cf['options'][$count_options]['value'] = (string) $custom_field->value;
        if ($custom_field->type == "dropdown") 
        {
          $count_opt = 0;
          $cf['options'][$count_options]['options'] = array();
          foreach ($custom_field->option as $option) 
          {
            $cf['options'][$count_options]['options'][] = (string) $option;
            $count_opt++;
          }
        }
        $count_options++;
      }
      elseif($custom_field->area == 'main')
      {
        $cf['main'][$count_main]['key'] = (string) $custom_field->desc;
        $cf['main'][$count_main]['label'] = (string) $custom_field->label;
        $cf['main'][$count_main]['type'] = (string) $custom_field->type;
        $cf['main'][$count_main]['value'] = (string) $custom_field->value;
        if ($custom_field->type == "dropdown") 
        {
          $count_opt = 0;
          $cf['main'][$count_main]['options'] = array();
          foreach ($custom_field->option as $option) 
          {
            $cf['main'][$count_main]['options'][] = (string) $option;
            $count_opt++;
          }
        }
        $count_main++;
      }
    }
    return $cf;
  }
```

According to the error it's referring to

> $cf = array('options' => '', 'main' => '');

Your help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Dumping the XML File

> object(SimpleXMLExtended)#483 (1) { ["item"]=> array(8) { [0]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLExtended)#484 (4) { ["area"]=> string(7) "options"
>   ["desc"]=> string(4) "slug" ["label"]=> string(8) "Slug/URL"
>   ["type"]=> string(4) "text" } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLExtended)#485 (4)
>   { ["area"]=> string(7) "options" ["desc"]=> string(4) "tags"
>   ["label"]=> string(32) "Tags (separate tags with commas)" ["type"]=>
>   string(4) "text" } [2]=> object(SimpleXMLExtended)#486 (4) {
>   ["area"]=> string(7) "options" ["desc"]=> string(4) "date" ["label"]=>
>   string(25) "Publish date (any format)" ["type"]=> string(4) "text" }
>   [3]=> object(SimpleXMLExtended)#487 (4) { ["area"]=> string(7)
>   "options" ["desc"]=> string(8) "category" ["label"]=> string(30)
>   "Assign This Post To A Category" ["type"]=> string(8) "dropdown" }
>   [4]=> object(SimpleXMLExtended)#488 (4) { ["area"]=> string(7)
>   "options" ["desc"]=> string(6) "author" ["label"]=> string(14)
>   "Author's Name:" ["type"]=> string(4) "text" } [5]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLExtended)#489 (4) { ["area"]=> string(7) "options"
>   ["desc"]=> string(7) "private" ["label"]=> string(15) "Post is
>   private" ["type"]=> string(8) "checkbox" } [6]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLExtended)#490 (4) { ["area"]=> string(4) "main"
>   ["desc"]=> string(5) "title" ["label"]=> object(SimpleXMLExtended)#492
>   (0) { } ["type"]=> string(5) "title" } [7]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLExtended)#491 (4) { ["area"]=> string(4) "main"
>   ["desc"]=> string(7) "content" ["label"]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLExtended)#493 (0) { } ["type"]=> string(8) "textarea"
>   } } }

Comment: Could you explain `$cfData = getXML(BLOGCUSTOMFIELDS);` a bit?

Comment: Are you sure with that (string) $option; because it can be array defined in foreach loop with any key like $option[xxx] ?? It look like $option is an array and can not be typed to string. And you should see row number where error was occured.

Comment: @IncredibleHat it's a flat file CMS saving data in XML file instead of DB the CMS is called GetSimpleCMS http://get-simple.info so here it's querying the data from the XML file related to BLOGCUSTOMFIELDS section

Comment: @daremachine the row number is 25 - 30 this one `$cf['options'][$count_options]['key'] = (string) $custom_field->desc;` till `$cf['options'][$count_options]['value'] = (string) $custom_field->value;`

Comment: Ok. Because, just copy pasting your code into a test script, I'm not seeing that fatal error (making up some output for getXML). Soooo I'm not sure why you are getting that error too!

Comment: try to change array('options' => '', 'main' => ''); to  array('options' => array(), 'main' => array());

Comment: @daremachine thanks this helped I missed this spot, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Change 

`$cf = array('options' => '', 'main' => '');` 

to
 `$cf = array('options' => array(), 'main' => array());`

The error says that

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Your code is wrong because you are trying add new key into $cf['options'] but it is string and not array

```
$cf['options'][$count_options] .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the release PHP 7.1+, is not more possible to initialize an array witrh
As of PHP 7.1.0, applying the empty index operator on a string throws a fatal error. Formerly, the string was silently converted to an array.